# Error install Ionic cordova in MacOS Sierra 10.12.3

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I install Ionic Cordova with this command line in macOS sierra 10.12.3:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic --unsafe-perm quickscrape
```

And I see this error:

> npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic" "--unsafe-perm" "quickscrape"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.10.2
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! syscall rename
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/it/npm-debug.log

How do can i fix this problem and install this?!

After Update npm with sural comment :

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic --unsafe-perm quickscrape
```

> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! syscall rename
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/abbrev-ef9cc920' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/abbrev'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/it/.npm/_logs/2017-04-13T11_36_41_762Z-debug.log

I need to found folder but i cant see this:

[image]

Comment: try `npm cache clean`

Comment: @suraj: same error!!

Comment: try updating npm..`npm install -g npm@latest` https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13528

Comment: @suraj: I see error after update npm. please see update Q.

Comment: I know this isnt exactly a perfect solution... but I would delete the .staging folder and try.. or unistall and reinstall cordova..

Comment: @suraj: i cant find .staging folder

Comment: check your error : /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Comment: @suraj: http://pasteboard.co/3MF7yoRew.png  node_modules folder

Comment: cant check that..can you add to the question?

Comment: @suraj: added now

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder